# display all values represented with keys by using JSONPath flutter flow

Tags: flutterflow

```
{
"code": 1,
"cities": {
    "25": "New York",
    "26": "Texas",
    "27": "Florida"
 }
}
```

I want to get all the cities. But since its structured as city ids as 25, 26, 27 etc on the other side, I am not able to target is as $.cities.title for example. I cannot modify the api coz it's external. May I know if there is way to handle such situation in flutter flow

I want the output to be like below

```
[
"New York",
"Texas",
"Florida"
]
```